# ImageJ API: how to get access to a straight line selection object in the java code?

Tags: java, imagej

I use [ImageJ 1.x API](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/) in my Java application, where I run ImageJ in invisible mode:

```
ImageJ imageJApplication = new ImageJ(2);
```

In my Java application I generate several images and open them for the user interactions:

```
Opener opener = new Opener();  
String imageFilePath = getLastImageFilePath();
ImagePlus imp = opener.openImage(imageFilePath);
imp.show();
```

I provide a user with the possibility to make a straight line selection on any of the opened images:

```
IJ.setTool(4);
```

If the user has drawn a straight line on an image, then I need to get length of this line. To do this I try to get access to the straight line selection object that was produced by the user interaction. Unfortunately I do not know where ImageJ creates and keeps this object.

I assume that it should be an object of `ij.gui.Line` class (the class that extends `ij.gui.Roi`). I know that to draw a `Roi` type object myself in a java program I would create an `ij.gui.Overlay` instance, add the `Roi` object to the overlay and then set the overlay to my target instance of `ImagePlus`. So I tried to look for the straight line selection objects in overlays of my opened images:

```
ImagePlus imp = WindowManager.getCurrentImage();
double lineLength = 0;

Overlay overlay = imp.getOverlay();
if (overlay!=null){
  for (int i = 0; i < overlay.size(); i++){
    if (overlay.get(i).isLine()){
      Line currentImageLine = (Line) overlay.get(i);
      lineLength = currentImageLine.getLength();
    }
  }
}
```

But for an image where a user has drawn a straight line the call `imp.getOverlay()` in the code above returns `null`. So, apparently, overlay is a wrong place to look for the user-produced straight line selection object instance. Does somebody know, how to get access to the straight line selection object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For questions regarding the ImageJ API, usually the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/) is the best place to ask.

> Does somebody know how to get access to the straight line selection object?

You were on the right track, but mislead by the `ij.gui.Overlay` class (that can contain an arbitrary number of `ij.gui.Roi` objects, but needs to be explicitly added to an `ImagePlus`).

To get the **current selection** from an `ImagePlus`, simply call `imp.getRoi()` (see also the [javadoc](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/index.html?ij/ImagePlus.html)):

```
ImagePlus imp = WindowManager.getCurrentImage();
double lineLength = 0;
Roi roi = imp.getRoi();

if (roi != null && roi.isLine()) {
    lineLength = roi.getLength();
}
```

---

One more comment:

```
ImageJ imageJApplication = new ImageJ(2);
 ...
IJ.setTool(4);
```

To keep your code more readable, use the defined constants instead of arbitrary integers:

```
ImageJ imageJApplication = new ImageJ(ImageJ.NO_SHOW);
 ...
IJ.setTool(Toolbar.LINE);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Tank you very much! Also thank you for the reference to ImageJ forum. I was not aware of it.